# Convergence in $L^p(\Omega)$ implies convergence of integral

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lebesgue-measure

The Hölder inequality for Lebesgue spaces is given as:
\begin{align*}
|| f g ||_{L_1(\Omega)} \leq ||f||_{L_p(\Omega)} ||g||_{L_{p'}(\Omega)}
\end{align*}
where $p, p'$ are the dual exponents.
Suppose $\Omega$ is bounded and that $f_j \to f$ in $L_p(Ω)$. Using Hölder’s inequality prove that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} f_j(x) \mathrm{d}x \rightarrow \int_{\Omega} f(x) \mathrm{d}x \ \ \text{as}  \ \ j \rightarrow \infty 
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Use the inequality $\|FG\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \le \|F\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\|G\|_{L^{p'}(\Omega)}$ with $F = f_j - f$ and $G = 1$ to get $$\|f_j - f\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \le |\Omega|^{1/{p'}}\|f_j - f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.$$

Then use the assumption $f_j \to f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ to conclude.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I am still missing point, how to get from assumption to conclusion ...

Comment: @SmallElephant since $f_j \to f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, then $\|f_j - f\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \to 0$. By the inequality I have above, this implies $\|f_j - f\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \to 0$. So $$\left|\int_\Omega f_j(x)\, dx - \int_\Omega f(x)\, dx\right| = \left|\int_{\Omega} [f_j(x) - f(x)]\, dx\right| \le \|f_j - f\|_{L^1(\Omega)} \to 0.$$